# How do you use document.getElementById( ) as part of a function with the target id being passed as the parameter

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I am trying to target a button using `document.getElementById`.
When the button is clicked I want the colour of the button to change to red.

My code currently looks as follows:

```
function selectDay (value) {
    var id = '"' + value + '"';
    console.log(id)
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

When I check the value of id this is always correct.

For example, if a button is clicked that has an id of 1 then in the console I will have "1". `document.getElementById("1")` should work but instead I am getting an error stating:

> Cannot read property 'style' of null.

I have double checked and the id in the html is definitely correct.

Comment: I suggest getting a good beginner's JavaScript book and working through it, so you get the basic concepts in place early. It'll save you a lot of time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes, just use `value` directly: `document.getElementById(value)`

You use quotes when writing IDs literally in your code because that's what tells JavaScript that what you're writing in the code is a string. But in your code, `value` is a *parameter* (almost identical to a *variable*). You want to use that parameter's value.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `selectDay (value)`, the parameter `value` is a string data type.

And in function `document.getElementById (id)`, `id` is string data type too.

Hence you can simply use:

```
function selectDay (value) {
    document.getElementById(value).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

and the use it as:

```
selectDay("button1")

OR

selectDay('button2')

OR

const button_id = "button3"
selectDay(button_id)
```

What went wrong in your code

```
selectDay("button1"); //lets suppose we call the function like this

function selectDay (value) {   //here value = [ b, u, t, t, o, n, 1] and is of type string
    var id = '"' + value + '"';//here id = [ ", b, u, t, t, o, n, 1, "] and is of type string
    console.log(id)
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";/*
here you function getElementById will return an error.

since there is no element in the HTML body that has attribute id = "\"button1\"" (which is [ ", b, u, t, t, o, n, 1, "])

the element you are trying to access has attribute id = "button1" (which is [ b, u, t, t, o, n, 1])
*/
}
```